# Passing object's variable to controller in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, variables, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create my very first CRUD ever.
Here's my journeySite.html table code.

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="trip : ${trips}">
        <td th:text="${trip.title}"></td>
        <td th:text="${trip.destination}"></td>
        <td th:text="${trip.id}"></td>
            <form th:action="@{/journeys}" th:object="${trip}" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" th:field="${trip.id}" />
                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And make a my controller looks now like that.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/journeys"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String journeysPage(Model model){
    tripRepository.save(new Trip("Asian Trip", "Asia"));
    tripRepository.save(new Trip("European Trip", "Europe"));
    tripRepository.save(new Trip("African Trip", "Africa"));

    model.addAttribute("trips", tripRepository.findAll());
    return "journeysSite";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/journeys"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String journeysPageTripDeleting(@RequestParam Long id) {
    tripRepository.delete(id);
    return "journeysSite";
}
```

**All i want is to show my all my trips on the /journeys in table. In each row there'd be a delete button which would POST trip.id, delete it from db and redirect to the exact same page, but with trip deleted.**

But obviously error has occured: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]`

Would anyone give me a tip how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At your form, you defined a `th:object="${trip}"` object which means whenever this form gets submitted this `trip` object will be sent as request body. 
So, to receive this object you have to accept it in controller's method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/journeys/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String journeysPageTripDeleting(@ModelAttribute  Trip trip){
    tripRepository.delete(trip.getId());

    return "redirect:/journeys";
}
```

The `th:field="${id}"` will be included with the object that model attribute provides so, `trip` object will have the id you're looking for.

More on [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/#initial).

**UPDATE:**
With your current controller's method implementation, I think all you need to change is this,

`<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" /> // No trip.id`

Comment: thanks for answer. Very usefull, now i know how it works for sure. The thing is i still get the error. Maybe my mistake is in the Controller responsible for get? It occurs when i request the /journeys

Comment: I've just reorganised the question. I'd be grateful if you could take a look at it now

Comment: still Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (journeysSite:17) :/

Comment: There was a syntax error in my updated answer. Could you check now?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'trip' available as request attribute

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your controller method post code from `@RequestMapping(value = {"/journeys/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)` to `@RequestMapping(value = {"/journeys/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)`.

As you can see,You forgot to add `{id}` in your RequestMapping which is required.

Also its standard to use `DELETE` http method for deleting an entity not `POST` method.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Still: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (journeysSite:18) in Chrome. In INTELLIJ i have java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'id' available as request attribute

Comment: Of course i did :) I wonder if there isnt a mistake in my html code.

Comment: @Karol.T , you can run your code in debugging mode and check whether value of id is coming inside your delete method.

Comment: It is not. The fun fact is that i'm having this error while i make a get request for /journeys. I've uptaded post with my "getController"

Comment: @Karol.T sorry i am confused here , i don't see your html code for GET code. and can you please format your question and include only the information which is required to make it more readable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136666/discussion-between-karol-t-and-amitk).

Comment: I've just reorganised the question

Answer (score 0):

This is not good practice to create form for each row. Instead do it this way:

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="trip : ${trips}">
        <td th:text="${trip.title}"></td>
        <td th:text="${trip.destination}"></td>
        <td th:text="${trip.id}"></td>
        <td><button class='delete' data-id="${trip.id}">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Add this js in your html:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<c:url value="/journeys/delete"/>",
                data: {
                    id: $(this).data("id")
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    location.reload();
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

And change your controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/journeys/delete"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String journeysPageTripDeleting(@RequestParam Long id) {
    tripRepository.delete(id);
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: You can even add delete confirmation in the JavaScript code.